# Prevent senders from breaking html newsletters

Tags: html, newsletter

So I've created a beautiful html newsletter, tested it across email clients and happy times are ahead. Then I give it to the client and they send it out. All jolly good.

But then when they want to send out another one the week after. They edit the html to their best knowledge and chop and change to update the content... and end up breaking something.

What do you guys recommend I do with my newsletters to prevent the senders from breaking them? I don't want to have to be involved with every single newsletter that is sent out. Is there an app or something similar to a "mini CMS" that I can use to help them edit the right parts of the code?

**EDIT**

Thanks both for your answers.

So I guess my best solution is probably just to think about this issue when I am designing the newsletters. Try to keep the content all in one place and whatnot.

Unfortunately for me, the company I work for runs about 60 e-commerce stores and they are all managed in house. So whenever one of the store managers break their newsletters they come to me to fix it... urgh I should be on commission!

Comment: If they don't have someone in-house with the knowledge to edit the emsils then they should be paying you to do the work. Simples.

Answer (score 0):

It's called billable hours - if they break it, that's money in your pocket for you to fix it. If they don't want to pay you for your time, then that's their problem.

This is a good thing :)

That being said, a templating system is a good idea anyway. Create a common header and footer and reference a "body" file which contains the guts of the newsletter. That won't necessarily eliminate the risk of broken HTML in the newsletter body, but it will make your future newsletter obligations less stressful.

There are also third-party emailer services with built-in WYSIWYG interfaces they could use if this is really just something you don't want to do anymore. I'd recommend something small like [MyEmma.com](http://MyEmma.com) to start, and build up based on the client's needs.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML of your newsletter is so case-specific that there is no "mini cms" that can do this out of the box. You'd have to write it yourself (or modify some existing templating system) to allow it to have the appropriate fields and free-form text areas. Even with this, you have to design your HTML in such a manner that when someone puts too much text in a given area that it does not break the layout.

This is a fairly complex problem that requires a moderate amount of effort to "idiot-proof" the whole thing. This become a custom application in its own right and does not come cheaply. You get what you pay for.

There are [services that provide this type of functionality](http://www.exacttarget.com/), but you still need to spend the time to configure them properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is willing to use a newsletter website (such as mailchimp, constant contact, cake mail), you could simple create a template where the client would be able to edit only certain fields.

That way, nothing would be broken but these websites cost money (depending on the plans offered)

If they insist that they want to send through an email software (outlook, apple mail, etc), they could sign up for a free account of cake mail, fill in the template, send the email to themselves and then just forward it (or better yet) copy paste in a new email and send it to their customers.

Comment: yeah! we are now using emailvision/campaign commander and the templates work brilliantly! Thank you all for your replies